# R' Yehoshua and the Athenian Elders: The mattress

Tags: talmud-bavli, maseches-bechoros

This is part of a [series of questions on the Gemara in Bechoros 8b-9a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22R%27+Yehoshua+and+the+Athenian+Elders%22+is%3Aquestion+user%3ADonielF). Below is a summary of the relevant parts of the Gemara. After being challenged by Caesar, R' Yehoshua went to Athens to defeat the Athenian Elders in a battle of wits.

---

In the process of their debate, the Elders asked R' Yehoshua to bring a kli not worth the damage it causes. He brought a mattress. Seeing it was too big to fit through the door, he asked that they should bring a pickaxe to widen the door.

If the Elders had asked this question here, it would probably be closed as being too broad. I can think of dozens of possible examples of ordinary household items they would have had back then not worth the damage they could cause - inkwells spilling all over expensive scrolls, glass shards getting stuck in people's feet, etc. So why did R' Yehoshua pick specifically a mattress getting stuck in a doorway?

Comment: To verify those stories you should find them in Greek sources. I seriously doubt that. But you probably look for a metaphorical explanation - Maarsh"a for example?

Comment: @Al You’re not the first to suggest looking at the Maharsha, I just haven’t worked on the sugya in a while to see what he says. I’m perfectly fine with a metaphorical interpretation.